# Calculating time taken for acceleration

Tags: kinematics, acceleration

about tickertape timer,when we measure the time for a particular object's acceleration, we would take 7 ticks multiply 0.020s(for example), instead of taking 8 ticks. Why do we exclude the other tick, is it because it will be more accurate?

Comment: try to count the time intervals between a pair of ticks....

Comment: If there is a field with a fence and you look at 8 fence posts, how many gaps are there?

Comment: Yup, I understand that. Let's say we have 7 dots, which is 6 ticks x 0.02s, but using this way to calculate for the total time taken, it is wrong on all the questions I have done from different sources. They tend to use 5 ticks x 0.020s, I don't know why... https://evantoh23.wordpress.com/2010/10/26/20101026ticker-tape-timer-finding-acceleration/